# Как взять значение с инпута и конвертировате его в массив? JS

Tags: javascript

У меня есть один инпут, мне нужно вводить его значение, которые разделяются запятой, в массив. Например: яблоко, груша, банан. Каждое слово разделенное запятой - отдельная переменная в масиве.

Comment: Who is "коммой"?

Comment: @Igor извиняюсь, это запятая

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы из строки сделать массив есть метод `split()`. В качестве аргумента передаём разделитель. Например:

```
"яблоко, груша, банан".split(", ");
// ['яблоко', 'груша', 'банан']
```